# Updating unrelated Vue.js variable causing input values in template to disappear

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I am having a weird issue with my single file Vue component where when I update an unrelated variable (Vue.js variable), all of my inputs (stuff I typed in, not the elements themselves.) disappear.

I have worked with Vue single file components for a few months now and I have never ran into something like this. Here is the weird part, the variable gets updated successfully as expected, but if I include the variable inside of the template at all that is when all the inputs disappear.

The function is looking up 'agents', then letting the user know how many records have been found and whether or not he/she would like to view them. If the user clicks on the "View" link, then they are shown a bootstrap-modal which shows them the records so that they could select one.

Here is what I have already tried:

1. Removing all ids from the inputs and using only refs="" to get the values.
2. changing the 'agents' variable name. Thought maybe it was conflicting with some rogue global or something.
3. Double checked that the parent component and this component was not being re-rendered. I did that by putting console.log() comments in the mounted() function and as expected it is only rendering once.
4. Watched the key using Vue dev tools extension to make sure the key was not being changed somehow.
5. Executed the `searchAgent()` function in a `setTimeout(()=>{},5000)` to see whether my use of _.debounce was causing issues.
6. Used jquery to fetch the values from the inputs instead of refs.
7. Assign the new records to a local variable agentsArray, then pass that into a function which assigns it to the vue variable 'agents' (its basically a needlessly longer route to the same thing but I thought WHY NOT TRY IT)
8. Double checked all my uses of 'this' to make sure that I was not accidentally using the wrong this and causing some unknown bug.
9. Using V-model, but using that doesn't help because I would still have to include the 'agents' inside of the modal in the template.
10. Using a v-if statement to render the modal HTML in the template only after 'agents' is not an empty array.
11. Update: Based on a suggestion, removed the function from inside of `$(document).ready()` inside of the `mounted()` function.

Template:

```
<template>
    <div class="Q mb-0">
        <a href="" id="help"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i></a>
        <center>
            <p class="display-1">{{title}}</p>
            <a href="#/" class="SkipStepStyle">{{prefix}} is Representing Themselves Skip This Step.</a>
            <div id="searchResults" class="hidden" style="margin-top:5px;">
                <a id="searchResultsText" class="SkipStepStyle"></a>
                <a
                        id="viewSearchResults"
                        style="font-weight: bold;"
                        class="hidden SkipStepStyle"
                        v-on:click="displayAgents"
                >
                    View
                </a>
            </div>
            <form class="mt-2 BuyerSellerAgentInfo">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input
                                ref="NameFirst"
                                type="text"
                                :name="prefix+'sAgent_NameFirst'"
                                placeholder="FIRST NAME"
                                class="AnswerChoice"
                                :value="currentAnswers[prefix+'sAgent_NameFirst'].Answer"
                        >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input
                                ref="NameLast"
                                type="text"
                                :name="prefix+'sAgent_NameLast'"
                                placeholder="LAST NAME"
                                class="AnswerChoice"
                                :value="currentAnswers[prefix+'sAgent_NameLast'].Answer"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input
                                ref="Email"
                                type="text"
                                :name="prefix+'sAgent_Email'"
                                placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS"
                                class="AnswerChoice"
                                :value="currentAnswers[prefix+'sAgent_Email'].Answer"
                        >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input
                                ref="Phone"
                                type="text"
                                :name="prefix+'sAgent_Phone'"
                                maxlength="14"
                                placeholder="PHONE #"
                                class="AnswerChoice"
                                :value="currentAnswers[prefix+'sAgent_Phone'].Answer"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input
                                ref="Brokerage"
                                type="text"
                                :name="prefix+'sAgent_Brokerage'"
                                placeholder="AGENT'S BROKERAGE"
                                class="AnswerChoice"
                                :value="currentAnswers[prefix+'sAgent_Brokerage'].Answer"
                        >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input
                                ref="License"
                                type="text"
                                :name="prefix+'sAgent_License'"
                                placeholder="AGENT'S LICENSE #"
                                class="AnswerChoice"
                                :value="currentAnswers[prefix+'sAgent_License'].Answer"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input
                        class="AnswerChoice"
                        type="hidden"
                        :name="prefix+'sAgent_ID'"
                        :value="currentAnswers[prefix+'sAgent_ID'].Answer || '1'"
                >
                <input
                        class="AnswerChoice"
                        type="hidden"
                        :name="prefix+'sAgent_BrokerageID'"
                        :value="currentAnswers[prefix+'sAgent_BrokerageID'].Answer || '1'"
                >
            </form>
        </center>
        <div v-if="agents.length > 0" class="modal" id="AgentPopup">
            <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
                <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <center>
                                <h5 class="d-inline-block mb-3">Select {{prefix}}'s Agent:</h5>
                            </center>
                            <button v-on:click="displayCategories" type="button" class="close shadow" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <ul>
                                <li v-for="agent in agents">{{ agent.NameFull || agent.NameFirst+' '+agent.NameLast }}</li>
                                <li class="border-0">{{prefix}}’s agent is not in this list</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
    export default {
        name: "AgentInformation",
        props: {
            friendlyIndex: {
                type: String,
                default: null,
            },
            title: {
                type: String,
                default: null,
            },
            answerChoices:{
                type: Array,
                default: () => []
            },
            currentAnswers: {
                type: Object,
                default: () => {},
            },
            prefix: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
            },
            token: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
            },
        },
        methods: {
            debounceFunction(func,timer){
                let vueObject = this;
                return _.debounce(()=>{
                    vueObject[func]();
                },timer);
            },
            displayCategories(){
                $('.categories').show();
            },
            displayAgents(){
                $('.categories').hide();
                $('#AgentPopup').modal({backdrop:'static',keyboard:false});
            },
            searchAgent() {
                let vueObject = this;
                console.log('calling searchAgent()');
                let agentSearchRoute = correctVuexRouteURL(vueObject.$store.getters.routeName('search.agent'));
                if (!agentSearchRoute) genericError('Agent Search Route Not Found. Error code: a-s-001');
                else
                {
                    let dataObject = {
                        NameFirst: this.$refs.NameFirst.value,
                        NameLast: this.$refs.NameLast.value,
                        Email: this.$refs.Email.value,
                        Phone: this.$refs.Phone.value,
                        License: this.$refs.License.value,
                        _token: this.token,
                    };

                    console.log(dataObject);

                    vueObject.$http.post(agentSearchRoute, dataObject).then((r) => {
                        let status = r.body.status;
                        if (status == 'success')
                        {
                            vueObject.agents            = r.body.agents;
                            let searchResultsContainer  = $('#searchResults');
                            let searchResultsText       = $('#searchResultsText');
                            let viewSearchResultsLink   = $('#viewSearchResults');
                            let agentCount              = 
   vueObject.agents.length;
                            searchResultsContainer.removeClass('hidden');
                            if(agentCount > 0)
                            {
                                let rText = agentCount > 1 ? 'records' : 
   'record';
                                searchResultsText.text(agentCount+' '+rText+' 
   found.');
                                viewSearchResultsLink.removeClass('hidden');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (!viewSearchResultsLink.hasClass('hidden'))
                                    viewSearchResultsLink.addClass('hidden');
                                searchResultsText.text('No records found.');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
        },
        data(){
            return {
                agents: [],
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            let vueObject = this;
            console.log('mounted');
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#phone').mask('(###)-###-####');
                $('.AnswerChoice').on('input', () => {
                    let searchAgent = 
  vueObject.debounceFunction('searchAgent',500);
                    searchAgent();
                });
            });

        }
    }
```

It seems that the issue is the template does not like the 'agents' variable to be inside of it. When I remove the modal container or just the references to 'agents' it works as expected. If I change the variable name it does not solve the issue.

Any thoughts on the solution? Am I missing something blatantly obvious and stupid?!

Edit: Something I forgot to add, I don't think affects this in any way but it is worth mentioning. This component is rendered dynamically inside of the parent.

Rendering the component:

```
<component
                            v-for="(component,i) in selectedView"
                            :is="component['Component']"
                            v-bind="bindAttributes(component)"
                            :key="component.ID"
                    >
                    </component>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'disappear'? Are they just hidden from view or are they no longer in the DOM? The `mounted` hook will only run the first time a component is rendered, subsequent rendering will trigger the `updated` hook. I am very suspicious of the jQuery `show`/`hide` stuff, that seems a likely candidate for your problem. Why not use Vue's `v-if` or `v-show` for that instead?

Comment: I mean the values I was typing in 'disappear', let me update the question. Thank you for asking that.

Comment: The issue does not seem to be related to my use of the ```show()```/```hide()``` but you do make a good point about using ```v-if``` and ```v-show```. I have tried this without any of the show/hide code and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `agents` will cause the whole template to be re-run. Not just the bits that mention `agents`, everything in that template will be updated.

When a user types into one of your `<input>` elements you aren't storing that value anywhere. You've got a `:value` to poke the value in but you aren't updating it when the value changes. The result will be that when Vue re-renders everything it will jump back to its original value.

You should be able to confirm this by setting the initial values within `currentAnswers` to be something other than empty. You should find that whenever `agents` changes it jumps back to those initial values.

The solution is just to ensure that your data is kept in sync with what the user types in. Typically this would be done using `v-model` but that's a bit tricky in this case because you're using a prop for the values and you shouldn't really be mutating a prop (one-way data flow). Instead you should use events to communicate the required changes up to whichever component owns that data.

Here is a simple test case to demonstrate the issue in isolation:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      count: 0,
      value: 'initial'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input :value="value">
  <button @click="count++">Click count: {{ count }}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay let me try developing a fix for that. Do you know if there is a way to prevent Vue from re-rendering certain parts of the template?

Comment: @RyanF In theory you can isolate rendering by breaking this up into more components, so that the inputs and `agents` aren't directly in the same template. Even if the parent re-renders it won't cause the children to re-render unless the props they're passed have actually changed. However, this really isn't the solution to your problem. It is really, really important that you get this fixed properly by ensuring the data is the primary source of truth. You shouldn't really be grabbing things using `this.$refs.NameFirst.value`, that value should already be in your data at that point.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that the template only re-rendered when the key was changed or it was re-mounted/forceUpdate, etc.